a way to trigger a css animation on a specific http header on an http response
I need a way to efficiently trigger a CSS animation based on a specific HTTP header in an HTTP response. My backend is in Rust, and I want the animation to play when triggered, rather than simply appearing. The solution would ideally rely on pure CSS and HTML for the animations.
Heres the HTML popup container
  <div class="ol-popup-container" id="ol-popupContainer" hx-put="/popup/show" hx-trigger="every 10ms">

and it should do this transition when it is triggered
 transition: bottom 0.5s ease-out, opacity 0.5s ease-out;


please provide minimum reproducible code. This helps readers to understand the issue better.

Example:
Rust Backend:
rust:
response.insert_header(("X-Trigger-Animation", "true"));

JavaScript:
fetch(window.location.href)
  .then(response => {
    if (response.headers.get("X-Trigger-Animation") === "true") {
      document.getElementById("animate-me").classList.add("animate");
    }
  });

CSS:
#animate-me.animate {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

